# How can I use Markdown in JSON on a Quarto website?

Tags: javascript, html, json, markdown, quarto

### Update: minimal reproducible example

In the following Quarto document, version 1 is interpreted as Markdown (see Update 2 below), but version 2 is not. What should I do to make version 2 work? You can find my motivation below.

```
---
format: html
---

<!-- version 1: this works (interprets Markdown) -->

<div>
**front1** $a^2$ $b + a$ [link](destination.qmd)
</div>

<!-- version 2: this does not -->

<div class = "question"></div>

<script>
var flashcards = [
  {
    "Q":"**front1** $a^2$ $b + a$ [link](destination.qmd)"
  }
]
const question = document.querySelector('.question');
question.innerHTML = `${flashcards[0].Q}`
</script>
```

---

### Update 2: how Quarto interprets LaTeX / Markdown

Quarto interprets version 1 from above as (for some unknown reason, I had to put double backslash instead of a single one):

```
---
format: html
---

<!-- version 1: this works (interprets Markdown) -->

<link href="test_files/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="quarto-bootstrap" data-mode="light">
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<p><strong>front1</strong> <span class="math inline">\\(a^2\\)</span> <span class="math inline">\\(b + a\\)</span> <a href="destination.qmd">link</a></p>
```

This yields the desired result. But putting this into version 2 feels very clumsy and still does not work:

```
---
format: html
---

<!-- version 2: this does not -->

<link href="test_files/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="quarto-bootstrap" data-mode="light">
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class = "question"></div>

<script>
var flashcards = [
  {
    "Q":"<div><p><strong>front1</strong> <span class='math inline'>\\(a^2\\)</span> <span class='math inline'>\\(b + a\\)</span> <a href="destination.qmd">link</a></p></div>"
  }
]
const question = document.querySelector('.question');
question.innerHTML = `${flashcards[0].Q}`
</script>
```

---

### Motivation

I implemented a simple flashcard app for my Quarto website, following [a nice YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=urf3kHQX7aI). The app works, but I want to use Markdown for the flashcard contents (to format LaTeX equations, links etc.).

My current implementation: I store the data for my flashcards in JSON format in the file `flashcards.js` and naively use Markdown here, but this is not interpreted when I render my Quarto website:

```js
var flashcards = [
  {
    "Q":"**front1** $a^2$ [link](destination.qmd)",
    "A":"back1"
  },
  {
    "Q":"front2",
    "A":"back2"
  },
  {
    "Q":"front3",
    "A":"back3"
  },
]
```

My `.qmd` is

```
---
format: 
  html:
    include-after-body: 
      - text: |
          <script src = "flashcards.js"></script>
          <script src = "reveal.js"></script>
---

<body onload = "getRandomCard()">
<div class = "question"></div>
<div class = "flashcard-button">
<button class = "check">Show solution</button>
<button class = "next">Next Card</button>
</div>
<div class = "answer"></div>
</body>
```

and the JavaScript to show a new flashcard and reveal the back is inside `reveal.js`:

```js
const question = document.querySelector('.question');
const answer = document.querySelector('.answer');
const check = document.querySelector('.check');
const next = document.querySelector('.next');
let card = -1;
let solution = false;

function getRandomCard() {
  let random;
  do {
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * flashcards.length);
  }
  while (card == random);
  card = random;
  question.innerHTML = `${flashcards[card].Q}`
  answer.innerHTML = `${flashcards[card].A}`
}

check.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (solution) {
    answer.style.display = 'none';
    solution = false;
  } else {
    answer.style.display = 'block';
    solution = true;
  }
});

next.addEventListener('click', function() {
  answer.style.display = 'none';
  solution = false;
  getRandomCard();
});
```

So my question is: Is it possible (and if yes, how) to use Markdown (for math equations, links) in my file `flashcards.js`? I feel like I am missing something simple here and hope that someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Note that maths is not part of markdown, that's something that *some* people have added to *some* flavours of markdown, in *some* applications. But it's one of those "I wish it were universal, but instead it's incredibly niche" things. Mostly because it's really hard to support. You either need an annoying front-end solution like katex or mathjax, which will constantly reflow your document, or you need to actually parse LaTeX server-side and then convert the result to something that works in the browser by using pdf2svg or the like.

Comment: Thanks, but luckily, Quarto provides both math and markdown (please see my example under "Update 2").

Comment: Looks like the markdown parser goes over the HTML that is contained in the document initially already, but won't parse any HTML that you add dynamically later on any more. So you'd have to see if there is any way to explicitly trigger that parsing again after content has been dynamically added.

Comment: If your LaTeX gets converted client-side, retriggering a conversion pass should be pretty simple, but does require the information of which library gets used in your post (should be fairly easy to find out with view-source/dev tools)